# Dbcontext disposed when iterating resulting list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

So I want to itterate a List i fetched from my Db and in a loop add items to a new list by fetching them one by one :

```
List<BasketItem> items = ps.basketRepo.GetUserItems(User.Identity.GetUserId()).ToList<BasketItem>();
List<BasketVM> vms = new List<BasketVM>();
foreach (BasketItem item in items)
{
    BasketVM vm = new BasketVM();
    vm.CoreItem = item;
    vm.ItemToestel = ps.ToestelRepo.GetByID(item.BesteldToestelId);
    vms.Add(vm);
}
return View(vms.ToList<BasketVM>());
```

This result in an error the likes of: 
**"The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."**

Any way of getting around this ? , I also tried using Include() in my linq query like this to get the extra objects in one go :

```
using (context)
{
    var query = (from b in context.BasketItem.Include(t=>t.SelectedToestel) where b.UserId==uId select b);
    return query.ToList<BasketItem>();
}
```

But it's not working , do I need to set a foreign key between the BasketItem & Toestel tables for this to work ?

thanks

EDIT : here are the involved models

```
public class BasketItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public Toestel SelectedToestel { get; set; }
    public int BesteldToestelId { get; set; }
    public int Aantal { get; set; }
    public String UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Toestel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public string Omschrijving { get; set; }
    public double AankoopPrijs { get; set; }
    public double HuurPrijs { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public string Afbeelding { get; set; }
    public List<OS> Os { get; set; }
    public List<Framework> Framework{ get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Yes you would navigation properties. Show you models for `BasketItem` and `Toestel`

Comment: Hey Stephen , I added the models in an edit

Comment: Please show your `ps.basketRepo.GetUserItems` method.

Comment: Suggest you read through [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj713564.aspx) to understand navigation properties.

Comment: I found a way around the problem , thanks for the help :) I'll read up on the nav properties ! thanks people

Comment: You may find interesting this post [Do I always have to call Dispose() on my DbContext objects? Nope](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html)

Answer (score 1):

In my repository I was accessing the Dbcontext with a **Using** statement , which disposes the context when going out of scope.

I cheesed my way around this by not writing the Using statement and **manually disposing of the Dbcontext**(field in my repository) when the iterating was done.

It's probably not the most clean way of doing it , but it works now !